# How can I repair a leaking crack in a Terrazzo stone bathtub?

Tags: repair, bathtub, stone

We have a terrazzo stone bath tub that has a crack that leaks. We love this bath and would love to find a way to fix it as it’s nothing we’ve seen before.

It has a stain on the bottom of it and the crack follows the outline of the stain. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

[image: the bath]

[image]

Comment: Does the stain disappear when the tub totally dries out?

Comment: How big is this thing? Can you easily disconnect and move it?

Comment: That looks like it is close to a meter wide, based on the block wall. I don’t know if I would try to move it for fear of making it worse. I would suggest a surface epoxy sealer. I might try a clear and coat the entire bottom to the point it starts up so it doesn’t show or it would not look as much like a patch. possibly sanding the surface first with a 600 grit wet dry paper. I use acid etches quite often but I don’t think i would want to chance enlarging the crack. Since the acid would also etch both sides of the crack.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert in this material, but here's my first inclination.

1. Turn the tub over in a good workspace.
2. Using a rotary tool (Dremel) or similar, channel out the outside of the crack to a depth of at least 1/4" (6mm). Keep this channel just the width of a carving bit--say 1/8" (3mm). Channel the entire length of the crack to a uniform depth, and taper out the groove just beyond the end of the crack.
3. Thoroughly clean out the channel with compressed air, alcohol, or soapy water (rinse well in the case of the latter). Allow it to dry thoroughly.
4. Fill the channel with a quality two-part epoxy. Work from one end and use masking tape to cover the channel as you work, containing the epoxy while it cures.
5. After curing, carefully sand the repair smooth with medium and fine-grit sandpaper, following any manufacturer instructions for such surface maintenance.
6. Reinstall the tub and test thoroughly.